# while loop sending multiple emails when a value is repeated

Tags: shell-script, email, variable

```sh
$IMPALA_CONNECTION -q "SELECT * FROM tbls_oldr_30"  |

while read DB_NAME TBL_NAME EMPE_USER_ID CREATE_TIME EMPE_SPVR_ID; do

  echo -e "Table 
  Name:$DBS_NAME.$TBL_NAME\nCREATED:$CREATE_TIME\nOWNER:$EMPE_USER_ID\n\nYour 
  table will be deleted on $new_date " |

  mail -E -r Myemail@email.com -s "Your table is over X days old" 
  $EMPE_USER_ID@email.com

done
```

The above script runs a query and stores its results in a variable. Then it sends an email to $EMPE_USER_ID@email.com. This works flawlessly; however, if there is more than one of the same $EMPE_USER_ID (let's say same user created several tables), it will send more than one email. What I'm trying to do is list all the variables and send them in one email.

Comment: what if the deletion date is different for each of the tables?

Comment: @jsotola good question so I have another variable that i didn't add to make things easier - new_date=$(date -d "$CREATE_TIME +90 day"  +%m-%d-%Y )

Comment: Sort the SQL result by EMPE_USER_ID, pipe into a subshell instead of while using ( ), track the change of EMPE_USER_ID in a helper variable and only ever send an email when this variable changed.